# Redirect batch output to cd command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cd

I have a batch file that outputs a path. How can I use the batch file in Windows cmd to change the current directory?

What have I tried:

```
F:\>cd my-path.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.

F:\>cd (my-path.bat)
The system cannot find the path specified.

F:\>my-path.bat | cd
F:\
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

my-path.bat content:

```
@ECHO OFF

@ECHO F:\MyPath\
```

Comment: You might try [setting it to an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2323292/10957435)

Comment: @Daniil Palii I rejected you edit suggestion to my answer because the second part made it non-functional. Because the `cd` command was inside `setlocal` ... `endlocal` its effect would be lost when the script ends. The first part would be fine: the main reason I did it the way I did was that for a "more substantial" original script, the `if` line can be dropped in at the beginning without affecting the rest of the script. Using `) else (` ... `)` as you suggested would nest the rest of the script unnecessarily. [**cont**]

Comment: [**cont**] However, using parentheses for the "then" block, and putting `cd F:\mypath` and `goto :eof` on separate lines would be fine, and I did in fact toy with doing it like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('my-path.bat') do cd /d "%~d"
```

Note: In a batch file you have to replace % by %%

Comment: Looks terrible and unusable but it works, thank You.

Comment: @DaniilPalii then you should switch to PowerShell, which has more elegant ways to handle such tasks. there you could just `cd (& ".\my-bat.bat")`

Comment: @SimonS, I like to have universal batch files to use it also in cmd and PowerShell, but You are right.

Comment: @SimonS, in Powershell I can type also `cd (my-path)` and `my-path | cd`

Answer (score 3):

For different drivers you need `/d` in your `cd` command

If your folder/path/name have any space/special character, use “double-quotes” too

```
@echo off 

echo\"F:\path to your folder"

:: or add/replace echo\"F:\path to your folder" to cd /d :: 
cd /d "F:\path\to\folder"
```

An alternative would be to get the output in a loop, where the bat would not be changed, just the command line...

```
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('^<con: "my-path.bat"')do cd/d "%~i"
```

- Remembering that loop variables `%i` in bat are `%%i`:

```
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('^<con: "my-path.bat"')do cd/d "%%~i"
```

---

- You can use arguments (`%*`) to variable run your command:

```
@echo off 

<con: call %* "F:\path to your folder" 2>nul || echo\"F:\path to your folder"
```

The `2>nul` suppression any possible error, and if the last command do not return 0, one simple echo will take action...

Using argument in your bat:

```
my-path.bat cd /d
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√]  **['Cd /d'](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

  [√]  **['For'](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√]  **['For /F'](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√]  **[Redirections in bat file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√]  **[Conditional Execution `||` and `&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√]  **[How can I pass arguments to a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-a-batch-file)**

  [√]  **[Understanding start, '2>nul', 'cmd', and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

Comment: @It_Wasn't_Me, what means "echo\" with a slash? I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: @DaniilPalii is the same `echo(` | `echo;` | `echo[` | `echo=` | `echo.` , just prevent `echo on` ... see `echo /?` in your prompt..

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply change your Batch file to:

```
@echo off

cd F:\MyPath\
```

Comment: I need this batch also in other cases and don't want to copy the code.

Comment: I only understood that you wanted to use this for the F:\MyPath\, but happy you found out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [LeRouteur's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1585628/347295), the following might be a useful compromise:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "." cd /d F:\mypath && goto :eof
echo F:\mypath
```

Running just `my-path` will echo the path, as it currently does, but running `my-path .` (i.e. with a single full-stop as a parameter) will change to that path.

If you dislike having the path entered twice, this can be avoided by using an environment variable, but to do so "cleanly" (without polluting your existing environment) needs a little thought:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "MYPATH=F:\mypath"
if "%~1" == "." (
    endlocal && cd /d "%MYPATH%"
    goto :eof
)
echo "%MYPATH%"
```

The use of `setlocal` means any changes to the environment (e.g. `MYPATH`) will only be made locally: running `endlocal` or reaching the end of the batch-file will revert to the original environment (see `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?`).

Using `setlocal` is very common in batch-files so that any environment variables they use/change don't "pollute" the main environment. The problem is that the *current directory* is part of what is localized: if you run `cd` while `setlocal` is in effect, you will return to your starting directory when the script exits.

One solution is to put the `endlocal` and `cd` commands on the same line. The way batch-files are parsed means that the *evaluation* of `MYPATH` happens while the environment is still "local" (so it still has the right value), but the *execution* of the `cd` command (using the value that was obtained in the first pass) doesn't happen until after `endlocal` has executed, meaning the directory *will* be changed when it returns to the command-line.

The way I define `MYPATH`, and use its value (enclosed in double-quotes) allows for the path to contain spaces. Perhaps not necessary here, but a good habit to get into when writing batch-files.

As a final option, you could replace `cd /d` with `pushd`. The latter "pushes" the current directory onto a stack before changing to the new one (see `pushd /?`). When you are finished doing whatever you need to do in `MYPATH` you can then run `popd` to return to whichever directory you originally ran `my-path .` from.